# Pulpish SF Zombie Short Story/Novelette

Tags: story-identification

I am almost certain I read this SF story in one of Ultimate Publishing's magazines (Amazing, Fantastic, or one of their all-reprint digests) between 1965 and 1970.
What little I can remember: it takes place in a city or base that is covered by either a force-field or a physical dome of some kind. Some kind of fungi or growth (probably alien) is clinging to the underside of the dome. This growth somehow kills people and reanimates them as zombies who want to kill the living.

In one scene the MC is talking to another man via visiphone; suddenly someone grabs the man by the hair and pulls him out of camera range. There is a scream and then the face of a zombie appears on the screen; it goes 'Argh!'. (Even as a kid I thought it was ridiculous and over the top, but I still want to read this story again.)

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is 'The Sheeted Dead' by Richard Rohrer, published in the September 1964 *Amazing*.
"Aahhhhhhgghahh." said the thing on the wall. A thread of saliva dropped from its lower lip, and its hand reached out, and the screen went blank.

Comment: I think it's *Robert* Rohrer, at least according to [ISFDb](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?60755).  Interesting that he's _also_ the author of the answer to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/129560/101407); his style must have been memorable for you.

Comment: Robert it is. I was concentrating on spelling 'Aahhhhhhgghahh' correctly. It was the horror elements that really stuck in my mind.